# Possible bug? using mapper on a list of list with the function size

Tags: rascal

I have encountered an issue in which I get an error in runtime on code which is valid according to  the compiler. The code is pretty simple. This also happens when you have a set[set[str]], but here I have listed the list[list[str]] version. I do not know whether it is exclusive to strings or if it can be any type.

> ```
> list[int] testMapperSizeListOfList() {
>     list[list[str]] a = [["a", "b" , "c"] , ["d"] , ["e", "f"]];
>     list[int] b = mapper(a, size);
>     return b;
> }
> ```

This is the error I get:

```
|std:///List.rsc|(8916,3,<394,56>,<394,59>): CallFailed(
  |std:///List.rsc|(8916,3,<394,56>,<394,59>),
  [["a","b","c"]])
        at mapper(|std:///List.rsc|(8912,25,<394,52>,<394,77>))
        at testMapperSizeListOfList(|project://series0/src/Prob3.rsc|(860,149,<32,0>,<36,1>))
        at $root$(|prompt:///|(0,27,<1,0>,<1,27>)ok
```

Just looking for some more info on what is happening and if this is intended.

EDIT:
The module is a bit bloated, with stuf that is probably not relevant to the issue, but here it is with the corresponding submodules.

```
module Prob3

import IO;
import Set;
import List;
import Map;

import lang::java::m3::Core;
import lang::java::m3::AST;
import lang::java::jdt::m3::Core;
import lang::java::jdt::m3::AST;

import Helper;
import Prob2;

tuple[int, int, list[str]] mostOccurringNumber(list[Declaration] asts) {
     map[str name, int amount] dic = countVariables(asts);
     map[int amount, set[str] names] invertedDic = invert(dic);
     
     map[int amount, int count]  lengths = (entry : size(invertedDic[entry]) | entry <- invertedDic, true);
     int highest = max(lengths.count);
     int mostCommonValue = getOneFrom(invert(lengths)[highest]);
     
     set[str] filteredNames = invertedDic[mostCommonValue];
     return <mostCommonValue, highest, toList(filteredNames)>;
}

list[int] testMapperSizeListOfList() {
    list[list[str]] a = [["a", "b" , "c"] , ["d"] , ["e", "f"]];
    list[int] b = mapper(a, List::size);
    return b;
}

list[int] mapperSizeListOfListInt() {
    list[list[int]] a = [[1,2,3] , [4] , [5,6]];
    list[int] b = mapper(a, List::size);
    return b;
}

 set[int] mapSizeSetSet() {
     asts = getASTs(|project://smallsql0.21_src|);
     map[str name, int amount] dic = countVariables(asts);
     map[int amount, set[str] names] invertedDic = invert(dic);
     
     int temp = size(getOneFrom(invertedDic.names));
     
     set[int] lengths = mapper(invertedDic.names, size);
     
     //set[list[str]] listTestt = mapper(foo.names, toList);
     //list[list[str]] listTest = toList(listTestt);
     //list[int] lengths2 = mapper(listTest, size);
     
     
     //return temp;
     return lengths;
}
```

Submodules:

```
module Prob2

import IO;
import Set;
import List;
import Map;

import lang::java::m3::Core;
import lang::java::m3::AST;
import lang::java::jdt::m3::Core;
import lang::java::jdt::m3::AST;


tuple[int, list[str]] mostOccurringVariable(list[Declaration] asts){
    map[str name, int amount] dic = countVariables(asts);
    int highest = max(dic.amount);
    set[str] correspondingNames = invert(dic)[highest];
    return <highest, toList(correspondingNames)>;
}

map[str,int] countVariables(list[Declaration] asts) {
    map[str name, int amount] dic = ();

    visit(asts){
        case \simpleName(str name):  dic = addToDic(dic,name);
        case \variable(str name , _ , _ ): dic = addToDic(dic,name);
        case \variable(str name , _ ): dic = addToDic(dic,name);
        case \fieldAccess(_ , _ , str name): dic = addToDic(dic,name);
        case \fieldAccess(_ , str name): dic = addToDic(dic,name);
        case \vararg(_ , str name): dic = addToDic(dic,name);
    }
    
    return dic;
}

map[str,int] addToDic(map[str,int] dic, str name) {
    if(name in dic){
                dic[name] = dic[name] + 1; 
            } 
            else{       
             dic = dic += (name: 1);
            } 
    return dic;
}
```

Helper submodule:

```
module Helper

import IO;
import Set;
import List;

import lang::java::m3::Core;
import lang::java::m3::AST;
import lang::java::jdt::m3::Core;
import lang::java::jdt::m3::AST;

list[Declaration] getASTs(loc projectLocation){
M3 model = createM3FromEclipseProject(projectLocation);
list[Declaration] asts = [];
for (m <- model.containment, m[0].scheme == "java+compilationUnit"){
asts += createAstFromFile(m[0], true);
}
return asts;
}

int getNumberOfInterfaces(list[Declaration] asts){
int interfaces = 0;
visit(asts){
case \interface(_, _, _, _): interfaces 
+= 1; 
}
return interfaces;
}
```

Comment: I'll have a look later today. If it is a bug, could you report it on GitHub pls?

Comment: Which version of Rascal are you using? Also, could you share the full module?

Comment: I've tested on 0.18.2 and there the result is simply `list[int]: [3,1,2]`. In earlier versions there have been fixes with higher-order functions. So I'm also curious which version you have.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know where to find that. I just downloaded it yesterday from the website. 

Edit: Nvm just saw it when starting the console it says version 0.18.2.

Comment: It is something to the specific module, since it does work when I put the function in a new module with only the corresponding imports.

Answer (score 2):

As you provided only a code snippet, please correct my suspicions/assumptions where needed.

- Are you importing the `Set` module as well?
- Does the error disappear when you fully qualify the `size` function? (i.e., replacing the third line with `list[int] b = mapper(a, List::size);`)

If so, you hit a bug with higher-order functions, and we would appreciate a bug report on [GitHub](https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/issues)! In the meantime, you could use this as a workaround.

EDIT:
I stand corrected. It seems that the type of the list elements is not derived correctly (`value` instead of `list[&T]`), which is a bug that has long been fixed, I believe. Is it possible for you to switch to rascal-unstable, to see if that solves your problem? It is available from a different update site (https://update.rascal-mpl.org/unstable).

Comment: <ul> 
I'am also importing the `Set` module.
The error does not dissapear when changing the line with the suggested.
</ul>

Comment: Alright, thanks. In that case, something else must be going on. Could you share your full module instead of only the snippet containing the function?

Comment: I edited the orginal question to give them. There a bit bloated with a lot of code which is probably irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: Running your version of Rascal, I've come to a different conclusion, and have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hypothesis: there is another variable or function named `size` in scope that somehow messes up the function compatibility. The two versions of `size` in Set and List merge to this type: `int (value)` and that seems to be ok. However, if there is a `size` function in scope, then something might go wrong. It could still be a bug though. 

If you click on `size` at the call site, where does Eclipse or VScode take you? How many alternative name resolutions are there?